# CCK field value count never less than 1 or NULL

Tags: drupal-6, cck

Ive got a CCK field set up so that unlimited values can be entered upon node creation (Number of values: unlimited)

When i try to print values in a node with

```
if ($node->field_tip != NULL)
 foreach ((array)$node->field_tip as $tip) {
 print "<div class='tip'>" . $tip['view'] ."</div>";
};
```

or print

```
count($node->field_tip);
```

the value is never less than 1, and `<div class='tip'></div>` is always displayed, even if there isn't any values entered in that field.

Answer (score 0):

The CCK field will never be null in Drupal 6.  Even if the field has no values, it will still be an array containing a single item.  You can check that the view attribute of each item is not empty before printing the div:

```
foreach ($node->field_tip as $tip) {
   if(!empty($tip['view'])) {
      print "<div class='tip'>" . $tip['view'] ."</div>";   
   }
}
```